# Integration in hyperbolic space

Tags: integration, analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $X$ be a smooth vector field, let $g$ be the metric tensor and $f$ be a smooth function with compact support in the upper half-space model of the hyperbolic space $H=\{(x_1, x_2,..., x_n)|x_n>0\} $.
The following inequality is a direct consequence of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:  $I=\int_H \langle X, \nabla_g f\rangle dV\le \int_H |X|_g|\nabla_g f|_gdV=\int_{H} \frac{|X|}{x_n} x_n |\nabla f| dx_1.dx_2...dx_n= \int_{H} |X||\nabla f|dx_1...dx_n$.

On the other hand, if we use the definition of $\langle X, \nabla_g f\rangle_g =\frac{1}{x_n^2} X\cdot \nabla_g f $ then we have
$I=\int_H \langle X, \nabla_g f\rangle dV=\int_H \frac{1}{x_n^2} X\cdot \nabla_{g} f dx_1.dx_2...dx_n\le \int_{H} \frac{1}{x_n}|X||\nabla f|dx_1.dx_2...dx_n$ where we have used the fact $\nabla_g f=x_n\nabla f$ and $|X|_g=\frac{|X|}{x_n}$. Here $dV=\frac{dx_1.dx_2...dx_n}{x_n^n}$ is the volume element. Can someone help me to understand why we are getting different upper bounds ? Is there any fact that I am missing?
Many thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you have done and where the discrepancy arose. Also the role of  hyperbolic space is unclear.

Comment: Many thanks for your comment Jan. I have tried to explain more this time.

Comment: For starters, I would think $dV$ refers to the hyperbolic metric. What is $|\nabla_g f|_g$?

Comment: $|\nabla_g f|$ represents the magnitude of the gradient of $f$ with respect to metric tensor $g$.

Comment: Does $dV$ here refer to the volume induced by $g$, or something else?

Comment: Yes $dV=\frac{dx_1.dx_2...dx_n}{x_n^n}$  is the volume element.